# Can I accept a call on iPhone without manual intervention?

Tags: iphone, call

I would like to know if I can accept a call without me or any person hitting the accept button?
It can happen immediately after receiving the call or after any number of rings, but automatic it should be.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called AutoAnswer, but it only works on jailbroken phones.  If you're into that sort of thing, you can find an article on it here:

http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/autoanswer-automatically-answer-specific-numbers-and-facetime-calls-on-your-iphone/

Comment: Thanks for the answer AJ, but I am looking for an Apple approved app.

Comment: Understood.  It is possible, but based on my searching only if you have a jailbroken phone.  Perhaps they'll add this feature to iOS at some point in the future.